# Original ip is seen by website on vpn server instead of private ip

Tags: nginx, ip, openvpn

I have a server (Ubuntu 16.04) on which I've set up openvpn server and jenkins with nginx. I want to be able to access jenkins.domain.com only by devices connected to openvpn. Here is a part of my nginx jenkins file

```
server {
listen 80;

root            /var/run/jenkins/war/;

access_log      /var/log/nginx/jenkins/access.log;
error_log       /var/log/nginx/jenkins/error.log;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name jenkins.domain.com www.jenkins.domain.com;

location / {
        allow 10.8.0.0/24;
        deny all;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        client_max_body_size 8m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
}
```

And now is the tricky part - I can connect to openvpn server and my device gets private ip - 10.8.0.6, every test I've found on internet says that's my ip address, but when I try to visit my jenkins.domain.com it say 403 Forbidden and in my nginx/jenkins/error.log I can see that actually there was only attempts to access this domain from orginal ip of my device.

Could anyone please help me, I'm looking for the answer for 3 days now and don't have any new ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `jenkins.domain.com` resolve to an internal or an external IP within the VPN?

Comment: To external one

Comment: Then the server is seeing your *external* IP, not the internal one when you access it. Use internal, split-horizon DNS so the domain resolves to the local address within the VPN.

Comment: Is the openvpn server the same machine running nginx, right? Edit your client's hosts file and force jenkins.domain.com to resolve to 10.8.0.1. If you manage to let it work, create another domain or hostname for private side connections.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried to follow yours instructions and I have one more question. I'm really new to servers and maintanance so I just went to my digital ocean page (I have my server from them) and set jenkins.domain.com to directs to 10.8.0.1. Is it ok or have I done something very stupid?

Comment: And to be clear - it's worked. I can access this website only when I'm in vpn